# QTreeView Move Item with Button

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using a QTreeView with a QStandardItemModel and I'm trying to figure out how to move items up and down the tree using buttons . I can do drag and drop no problem, but what I would like to do is have some buttons associated with "move up" and "move down" functions. I just cant find anything on the subject. There seems to be a "moveRow()" function for the model object, but I cant find any documentation on it so I'm not sure if its what I need. Any information you could give to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

PS Here are my QT Creator stats:
Qt Creator 2.6.2 
Based on Qt 5.0.1 (64 bit)

Comment: Did you actually get this to work? moveRow() is a virtual function, right, so you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hunch is correct. `moveRow()` is the right function to call.

To move items within one parent (it's a tree, after all), you'd do `moveRow(parent, index.row(), parent, index.row() + delta)`, where `delta` is set to 1 or -1 depending on whether you move down or up, respectively.

If you want to allow items to be moved between parents, you'll need additional logic to figure out the destination parent if the item would be moved past its parent.

Do note that it's considered bad design if the move button are separate from the items to be moved. Your delegate should display up and down arrows for each item, in its row, so that you can move things with one click. When there is a contiguous selection, the delegates should merge the up/down arrows to cover all of the items. When the selection is non-contiguous, the up/down arrows should disappear.

With separate buttons, you need two clicks: first select the item, then click up/down. This  *sucks* from user experience point of view.

Comment: I believe that there is no built-in working function `moveRow`, but rather it is one of those parts of QAbstractItemModel that you must build yourself. (And those in Qt4, unlike the OP, there is no moveRow virtual function, so you are doubly out of luck :)).

Comment: @neuronet Of course it's a part that the model must implement, but that's a given. We're talking about the view here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `moveRow` is a method of `QAbstractItemModel`, not `QTreeView`. Given that the user must implement it, I don't see how your answer is really an answer, though it does have interesting opinion on optimal design. I will post some working code later if I get the time. Since the OP asked about `QStandardItemModel`, there are pretty easy ways to implement it.

Comment: @neuronet The question wasn't how to implement `moveRow` in a model, it was about how to move rows when you're implementing a view/controller - and the answer is that you call `moveRow`. Since `QStandardItemModel` doesn't provide an implementation, one would have to provide it in a derived class - or add it to Qt sources :) All that I'm saying is that you shouldn't tie your view to a particular model's shortcomings and call something model-specific. The view expects `moveRow` to work, and the model provided to it must support it too. That's the only sane way to deal with it.

Comment: I now understand. I think you might be aiming a bazooka at a mouse. :)  If the goal is to build a fast, flexible, generalizable tree model by subclassing QAbstractItemModel, then I'd agree with you. But the OP is subclassing QStandardItemModel, which already tells us that is not his goal (well, that, or he is not sure what he is doing, but I'm going to be charitable). At any rate, I came here hoping for a simple solution,and am close to having one: I would be curious to see what you think once I finish it. :)

Answer (score 0):

`moveRow` doesn't seem to work in `QTreeView`.

Here's a simple (PyQt5) solution for moving an item "up one" relative to its sibling(s). It must have at least one sibling "above". Also this is only for moving between siblings, not where you want to move a row to a different parent. However, I think that these issues could be engineered without difficulty on the basis of this code.

One thing to be aware of here is that the `QStandardItem` doesn't change in operations like this, but that the associated `QModelIndex` does.

```
# in almost all QTreeView implementations the "tree" structure is at column 0...
curr_index = self.selectionModel().currentIndex().siblingAtColumn(0)
if curr_index.isValid():
    curr_item = self.model().itemFromIndex(curr_index)
    curr_row = curr_index.row()
    # if this is the top sibling of its parent it cant be moved up... 
    if curr_row > 0: 
        parent_item = self.model().itemFromIndex(curr_index.parent())
        # NB parent_item is None in the case of root children: 
        # in that case you therefore use "takeRow" and "insertRow" methods of the model, not the item!
        take_row = self.model().takeRow if parent_item == None else parent_item.takeRow 
        insert_row = self.model().insertRow if parent_item == None else parent_item.insertRow 
        row_to_move = take_row(curr_row)
        insert_row(curr_row - 1, row_to_move)
        new_index = self.model().indexFromItem(curr_item)
        # now set the (single) selection, and set current,  back to the moved item 
        # (if you are implementing single-selection, obviously)
        flag = QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.SelectionFlag
        self.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(new_index, flag.Clear | flag.SelectCurrent)
```